# How to pass styles arguments to Style from a wrapper function's argument?

Tags: replacement, output-formatting, notebooks, style, arguments

The user-defined symbol `styx` works fine for `style` argument values of `Automatic` and `True` but returns unevaluated when `style` argument set to a `List` or `Sequence` containing `Style` attributes. Been trying to figure this out for hours. Please help.

Below is a stripped-down skeletonized version of what I have so far.

```
ClearAll[styx]
SetAttributes[styx, HoldRest];
styx[Rule[x_, y_], style_ : Automatic] := With[{
    col = Options[EvaluationNotebook[], FontColor],
    stx = {Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier New"},
    gry = GrayLevel[.5],
    alt = RGBColor[.625, 1, .625]
    },
   Which[
     MatchQ[style, Automatic] && StringQ[x], 
     Style[InputForm[x], gry, stx],
     MatchQ[style, Automatic], Style[InputForm[x], alt, stx],
     style, Style[InputForm[x], col, stx],
     ListQ[style] || Head[style] == Sequence, 
     Style[x, style] /. {___} -> Sequence[___],
     True, x] -> y
   ];
```

Below are some runs with their results in comments. Thank you.

```
(* FIRST 3 STRING KEY RUN FINE *)
styx["str" -> "string"]
styx["str" -> "string", Automatic]
styx["str" -> "string", True]
styx["str" -> "string", {Orange, Italic}] (* List does not evaluate *)
styx["str" -> "string",Sequence[Orange, Italic]](* Sequence does not evaluate *)

(* FIRST 3 WITH SYMBOL KEY RUN FINE *)
styx[Frame -> True]
styx[Frame -> True, Automatic]
styx[Frame -> True, True]
styx["str" -> "string", {Orange, Italic}](* List does not evaluate *)
styx["str" -> "string",Sequence[Orange, Italic]](* Sequence does not evaluate *)
```

Comment: `style, Style[InputForm[x], col, stx],` ...`style` is not a test

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch i dont understand what youre saying.

Comment: "Which" takes pairs of:" test, expression". "test" must be an expression that returns True or False. However "style" does not return true or False.

Comment: @DanielHuber thank you its fixed. :)